# Issue stopping iPhone resizing HTML e-mails

Tags: iphone, html, css, html-email

I'm having an issue trying to prevent the iPhone from resizing HTML e-mails to fit the screen. It seems that code below when put into the  section has no effect.

My goal is just to stop the font re-sizing. I've tried other variations using -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; inline and in other way, all without success.

Would grealty appreciate any advice or an alternative solution.

> @media screen and
>   (max-device-width: 480px){
>
> ```
> /*fixes too big font in mobile Safari*/
> html, body, form, fieldset, p, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
> -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; }  }       </style>
> ```

Comment: You're talking about layout resizing and you try to avoid font resizing. Are you sure the problem is not with the tables or something else you have in your HTML?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer -- all I'm looking to do is stop the font re-sizing. No matter how or where I use -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; it doesn't seem to work. I've tested it in Litmus extensively.

Comment: Stylesheets (inline or otherwise) are often ignored in email (or stripped entirely). Try setting it on a `style` attribute instead, perhaps?

Comment: Tried it on the body tag inline with no luck. Wondering if it's just not possible to control.

Comment: I don't know that this is possible, I am commenting to track it if you find a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

The iPhone seems to be a pain when it comes to resizing things, especially when you switch the orientation of the phone. Have you tried adding the meta tag with viewport settings in it?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
```

It does prevent them from zooming, but I haven't found any better way to stop the iPhone from zooming on orientation change. I'm not sure if this will help in this situation, but just a suggestion to try out.

Comment: Good suggestion. Had tried something similar and this, and it doesn't seem to make a dent. The whole e-mail is re-sized automatically to fit the screen making the type too small.

Comment: Just a note, the inclusion of this metatag will cause Blackberrys to display a blank screen instead of any email.

Answer (score 3):

I been stuck w/ this problem and there's no available solution on the net that works.
Not until I realized what's causing this.

**CAUSE:**
This problem occurs if you have an image w/in the email. When the image auto-scale, the entire email/page will auto-fit in the window.

**SOLUTION:**
Add inline style for the image for **min-width** (300px so it doesn't take the entire 320px iphone width), **max-width** (your desired max with), and **width of 100%**.

i.e.
 image src="image.jpg" style="width: 100%; min-width: 300px; max-width: 500px;"

Worked for me, ...hoping this can help you too! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is correct but the problem is that rather than using `-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;` inside a style tag, you should use it in the below manner:

```
<body style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">
```

This means you should use this as an inline css property.

Comment: So I tried adding it inline, and I've also removed the media queries. The Litmus tests still show the whole e-mail re-sized to fit and the text shrunk down, so it still is adjusting the font size.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of that problem you have to put the following in your CSS body tag:

```
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
```

This way Safari keeps the text to 100% of intended size. In case you set the value to none, the users won't be able to increase the font and this is an undesired behavior.

This CSS property is supported and should work.

Check the official Safari supported CSS reference:

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html

Furthermore please note that the media type screen is supported in:

- Safari 4.0 and later.
- iOS 1.0 and later.

I hope this helps.

BR,
Tolis

Answer (score -1):

A retina iPhone has a 640px width, your media query stops at 480px.

Anyway, you can get rid of the media query altogether. The only webkit based mail client that will use this property (`-webkit-text-size-adjust:none`) is iPhone's and iPad's Mail app.

Also the Mail app may also be the only client supporting CSS3

Comment: Retina displays have the same screen sizes, only the DPI change. It respond to the same media queries as old iPhones.