# HTML responsive email zooms out on iPhone, perfect on Android

Tags: android, iphone, responsive-design, html-email

I designed an email template specifically for mobile by using % for widths and em for fonts to test out for my company. The email looks as intended on Android 2.2, but it is initially zoomed out on iPhones.

I know about the meta viewport but I'm worried as it looks like our email system (a little outdated) strips out all content from the HTML file taking only what's in between the body tags. Will the iPhone always display it zoomed out without this, or am I totally overlooking something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use and it works for both Android and iPhone beautifully:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />`

and the following media query:

@media screen and (min-device-width:320px) and (max-device-width:760px)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it on the link below, you might want to try it:

[Issue stopping iPhone resizing HTML e-mails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801685/issue-stopping-iphone-resizing-html-e-mails/24055721#24055721)

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow as they are vulnerable to [link rot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot). Please add the relevant details to your answer and only use the link as a reference.